# WPF Sliderf follow cursor

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, slider

I have slider :

```
<Slider x:Name="DesktopAudioSlider"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Margin="0,0,5,0">
```

I need behavior like in UWP Slider ,  that follow the cursor when it click. I cant use events because use MVVM ,  tried to convert sender and eventargs to tuple and pass to command , but there is no way how to pass MouseEventargs to converter.

Converter :

```
class SliderArgsToTupleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(parameter is MouseEventArgs)
            {
                return new Tuple<object, MouseEventArgs>(value, parameter as MouseEventArgs);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Command :

```
this.SlideMouseMoveCommand = new RelayCommand<Tuple<object, MouseEventArgs>>(SlideMouseMoveExecute);
```

Trigger :

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MixerViewModel.SlideMouseMoveCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DesktopAudioSlider , ConverterParameter={}}"
                        </i:EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way how to pass two arguments in command , i found the one solution - add behavior.

```
public class SliderMoveBehavior : Behavior<Slider>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove += SliderMouseMove;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= SliderMouseMove;
        }

        private void SliderMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Point position = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
                double d = 1.0d / AssociatedObject.ActualWidth * position.X;
                var p = AssociatedObject.Maximum * d;
                AssociatedObject.Value = (int)p;
            }
        }
    }
```

In XAML :

```
<Slider x:Name="PlaybackSpeedSlider">
     <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <behaviors:SliderMoveBehavior/>
     </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Slider>
```